# How to repeat code after an exception in python

Tags: python

So i'm new to python and i was wondering how to repeat code after an exception.

Like for and example:

```
try:
    number = int(input('Enter a number: ')
    print(number)
except ValueError:
    print('You must enter a number')
```

so insted of ending the code I would want to make the `Enter a number:` input appear again after without repeating the same code again.

Comment: It's time to learn loops. [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp

If you don't want it to repeat if it's successful add keyword 'break' after print.

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input('Enter a number: ')
        print(number)
    except ValueError:
        print('You must enter a number')
```

Comment: I meant repeating the code after after the error appears like if some1 types letters into the output instead of the numbers

Comment: This will work, if you don't want it to repeat after correct input add the work "break" after print(number)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop like this:

```
is_no_number = True
while is_no_number:
    try:
        number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        print(number)
        is_no_number = False
    except ValueError:
        print('You must enter a number')
```